# How to customize zeppelin dynamic forms?

Tags: css, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

Is it possible to overwrite the zeppelin dynamic forms input design? I am  using with zeppelin with  Pyspark and I need to change the CSS style of  zeppelin dynamic forms.

In my case, I have `input_1 = int(z.input('Number of entities', '0'))` and I would like to overwrite CSS class so I can play with the width, height, etc.